# Trigger an AutoHotkey script when Windows orb (menu button) is clicked

Tags: autohotkey

I have an AutoHotkey script that I would like to run whenever the Windows 7 start menu orb is clicked (the button on the bottom left that brings up the menu).

I've been using `MouseGetPos` previously to determine when the cursor is hovering over the region, but this causes the script to be activated even when running fullscreen applications. Is there another way I can use to detect when the start menu orb is clicked? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
MouseGetPos,,, id, control
WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %id%
WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%

if (title = "Start" || (class = "Shell_TrayWnd" && control = "")) {
    ;Do script
}
```

`title = "Start"` covers most of the orb, except for a few pixels at the corners.

`class = "Shell_TrayWnd"` refers to the entire taskbar, but only the few pixels around the orb do not have a value for control.

This should cover the entire region where normally clicking would bring out the Windows menu.